# Windmill getPageText function never ends

Tags: python, web-scraping, windmill

Some days ago I started a project where I need to create a web scraper. An user suggested me to try Windmill.

Everything is fine but I have a problem: when I call to getPageText() function it sometimes hungs and never ends. I have tried some possible solutions but without success. Besides, I haven't found any information about this problem so I don't know how to proceed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
client.waits.sleep(milliseconds=12000)
client.waits.forPageLoad(timeout='60000')
```